# C++ instanciation

Tags: c++, instance

I want to have an instance of a class in another one. If I  create the object in the main program, everything is fine. If I remove comment in front of line 13, I receive message

```
g++ MyMWE.cpp 
MyMWE.cpp:13:14: error: expected identifier before string constant
   delay1 DTT("DELAY1", 6);
              ^
```

What is the difference if I instanciate in the main program or in the class? And, what identifier is expected by the compiler? What do I wrong?

```
#include <string>

class delay1 {
public:
  delay1(std::string name, int t_){}
  int t;
};

class delay2 {
public:
  delay2(std::string name, int t_){}
  int t;
//  delay1 DTT("DELAY1", 6);
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  delay1 DTT("DELAY1", 6);
  return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In-class initializers must use the `=` or `{}` initialization syntax:

```
class delay2 {
  // ...
  delay1 DTT{"DELAY1", 6};
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, although it needs to add " -std=c++11". Otherwise I receive the error message "extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11". Could you please give a pointer, what is the effect without the switch or using other standards?

Comment: @katang C++03 did not support in-class initializers at all. You could only initialize members in the constructor's member initialization list.